# Short int doesn't take the value

Tags: c, compiler-construction

The input given to following program is

10 10

10 10

But the output is

0 20

Why ?

```
/* scanf example */
#include <stdio.h>


int main ()
{
    short int a, b, c, d, e, f;
    a=b=c=d=e=f=0;
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    scanf("%d %d",&e,&d);
    c=a+b;
    f=d+e;

    printf("%d %d\n",c,f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    short int a, b, c, d, e, f;
    a=b=c=d=e=f=0;
    scanf("%hd %hd",&a,&b);
    scanf("%hd %hd",&e,&d);
    c=a+b;
    f=d+e;

    printf("%d %d\n",c,f);
    return 0;
}`

Comment: No, I know that to enter short int %hd is required but I want to know the reason behind this behavior when we use %d.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have taken 6 variables a, b, c, d, e, f. The memory allocated by them are 2 bytes and the  starting memory address are say for f 0x0, e 0x2, d 0x4, c 0x6, b 0x8, a 0xa

when you are doing 
scanf("%d %d",&a,&b)
first value for a is written from memory location 0xa, occupying 4 bytes till 0xe. Then value for b is written starting from location 0x8 occupying 4 bytes till 0xc, thus overwriting memory location of a. same with other scanf. You will get different values if you change the order of memory location.

Please note output is dependent on the platform you are using hence undefined behaviour

Answer (score 8):

The correct `scanf` format specifier for `short int` is `%hd`, not plain `%d`. You are experiencing the results of *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

Because the stack gets corrupted.
Suppose the "short int" type takes 2 bytes on your platform, while the "int" type takes 4 bytes. Variables a, b, c, d, e, f are allocated on the stack and they are assigned 2 bytes each. Each time you read a value using the "%d" specifier, instead of "%hd", you tell scanf() to memorize it as an "int", taking 4 bytes instead of 2. That produces, of course, unpredictable results. 
In my experience, the usage of scanf() gives more headaches than benefits :-) so you might want to use the safer fread() and then convert the string into an integer.